# How can I copy hex data of captured packet from Charles Proxy?

Tags: hex, charles-proxy

here is an example of the data I see on Charles proxy:

```
00000000  0a b9 02 30 33 41 47 64 42 71 32 36 6d 41 49 5a      03AGdBq26mAIZ
00000010  38 63 4d 41 53 79 32 46 78 43 52 63 7a 33 4a 6c   8cMASy2FxCRcz3Jl
00000020  51 4d 6a 6c 49 47 4f 6f 4d 6b 4a 51 75 51 5a 73   QMjlIGOoMkJQuQZs
00000030  4b 64 4d 59 58 6d 35 31 43 74 75 39 76 70 5a 4c   KdMYXm51Ctu9vpZL
00000040  79 43 4f 37 65 39 79 53 6e 55 52 39 6b 34 4b 49   yCO7e9ySnUR9k4KI
00000050  63 51 74 44 62 5f 30 52 4a 69 76 79 35 46 43 6f   cQtDb_0RJivy5FCo
00000060  5a 67 59 50 63 63 4c 7a 66 62 79 63 42 4a 42 70   ZgYPccLzfbycBJBp
00000070  68 73 4c 47 5f 65 71 4e 64 58 7a 79 75 4b 33 32   hsLG_eqNdXzyuK32
```

I wanna copy only the hex part. Like:

```
0a b9 02 30 33 41 47 64 42 71 32 36 6d 41 49 5a
```

I have been searching for a solution but haven't found anything. How can I do that?